# Moishezon manifold vs proper complex variety

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

Does there exist a closed Moishezon manifold that does not have the homotopy type of the analytification of a smooth proper complex variety (I think we know that every closed Moishezon manifold is bimeromorophic to the analytification of a smooth proper complex variety, so for example fundamental groups have to be the same)?

Does there exist a smooth proper complex variety whose analytification is not homotopy equivalent to the analytification of a smooth projective complex variety?

Comment: By the way, not every Moishezon manifold comes from a proper complex variety; it might be an algebraic space instead of a scheme. There is an example due to Kleiman which is a quotient of Hironaka's example.

Comment: @Ben that is true of course but we are interested in whether that distinction is visible at the topological level

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit off today. I misunderstood something you wrote.. (I thought you were suggesting hat every Moishezon manifold is the analytification of a proper variety.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** I just realised that the OP asked for proper, not projective varieties. As it stands, it is still possible that Oguiso's Moishezon Calabi-Yau threefold is homotopy equivalent to a proper varitey, so the question remains open.

---

The only example I am aware of is due to Oguiso, *[Two remarks on Calabi-Yau Moishezon threefolds](https://doi.org/10.1515/crll.1994.452.153)*, J. reine angew. Math. 452 (1994). There, you find a construction of a Moishezon threefold $X$ with $H^2(X) = \mathbb{Z}c$ where $c^3 = 0$. In particular, $X$ is not even homotopy equivalent to a Kähler manifold.